# Is there function in powershell to detect a symbol in a comma separated text file and replace that symbol(s) with data from the same file?

Tags: powershell, regexp-replace

I have a text file saved in drive C:\ with data similar to the following:

```
John, II23T, 123456, ABCCD
Jane, II23T, 123654, ABCCD
J???, II23T, 132456, ABCCD
??????, II23T, 1422345, ABCCD
??hn, II23T, 432562, ABCCCD
```

I found the link below which discusses how to detect and replace symbols including "?" but I could not figure out how to get to the data to replace the affected.
[Use Powershell to replace characters within a specific string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17412728/use-powershell-to-replace-characters-within-a-specific-string)

In summary, my goal is to detect and strip the "?" symbol and replace with numerical data 2 commas to the right of the line in order for me to get the following result.

```
John, II23T, 123456, ABCCD
Jane, II23T, 123654, ABCCD
132456, II23T, 132456, ABCCD
1422345, II23T, 1422345, ABCCD
432562, II23T, 432562, ABCCCD
```

Please help a noob here... let me know if more info is needed.
Thanks a mil!

Comment: What have you tried, where are you stuck? Please [edit] the question and share a [mcve] of your coding attempts! Otherwise, this post is noting but a code/script request, which is clearly off-topic here! Please take the [tour], visit the [help] and learn [ask] here!

Comment: Edited the question as requested. I need help on how to detect and replace all lines in a text file with the symbol "?" and replace with the numeric data 2 commas to the right.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Import-Csv` cmdlet to easily process this.

## Changing the data

Assuming you have column names as follows (the column names are samples, you can insert your own into these examples):

```
Name, Col1, Col2, Col3
```

You can process each line as follows:

```
# Read the CSV file into an easy-to-use object
$csv = Import-Csv "C:\Path\To\file.csv"

# For each line in the CSV
$csv | Foreach-Object {

  # Check if the name contains a literal ?
  if( $_.Name -match '\?' ){

    # If the name contains a literal ?, make the name equal Col2
    $_.Name = $_.Col2
  }
}
```

If you don't have header names in your CSV, fret not, you can create some temporary ones on the fly:

```
Import-Csv -Header Name, Col1, Col2, Col3 "C:\Path\To\file.csv"
```

## Writing the changes back to CSV

If you want to write back to a CSV after changing the data, you can then use the `Export-Csv` cmdlet:

```
$csv | Export-Csv -NoTypeInformation "C:\Path\To\file.csv"
```

However, if you don't want headers as part of the exported CSV, `Export-Csv` doesn't support this. You'll need to get creative:

```
$csv | ConvertTo-Csv -NoTypeInformation | Select-Object -Skip 1 | Out-File "C:\Path\To\file.csv"
```

What the above does is convert the `$csv` object to a CSV string. `Select-Object` is then used to skip the first line which contains headers, and `Out-File` writes the CSV string to file.

Comment: For what it's worth, you don't need to read the data into the variable `$csv`; you could just pipe `Import-CSV` to the `ForEach-Object...`, and then, if desired, pipe _that_ to `Export-CSV`, `ConvertTo-CSV`, or `Out-File`.

Comment: True, but I wanted to make each line clear and concise. You can do many clever things with the pipeline but IMO it makes it less clear to instruct.

Comment: Very greatful for the the info share here @BendertheGreatest